# VMWare Server 2.0 set processor affinity

Tags: linux, vmware-server

I am running VMWare Server 2.0 on a Debian Lenny box that has two Opteron cores.  I am wondering if there is a way to manually set the processor affinity so that Virtual Machines 1 & 2 get fired off of a single processor, and Virtual Machine #3 gets fired off of the other processor?

I understand that this is not a feature out of the box, but there might be a command line hack that could get me where I want to be :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the affinities after the fact using `taskset`. I'd personally use a script that prioritizes or sets the CPU affinities the VMWare `vmware-vmx` processes. Drop it in cron hourly or have it run once. For instance, a typical VMWare Server 2.0 `ps aux` output looks like:

```
[root@xxxx ~]# ps auxwww| grep vmx
root     30372 24.9  1.1 2026132 137092 ? S<sl  2010 25896:06 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -# product=2;name=VMware Server;version=2.0.2;buildnumber=203138;licensename=VMware GSX Server for Linux;licenseversion=3.0 build-203138; -@ pipe=/tmp/vmhsdaemon-0/vmxd6074b323529c88a;readyEvent=40 /vmware/xxxx_Web/xxxx_Web.vmx
```

To set that to CPU core 2, I'd use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set CPU affinity for vmware-vmx processes to CPU core 2
for i in `pgrep -f vmware-vmx | xargs`; do taskset -c -p 1 $i; done
```

Or you can manually run `taskset` on the relevant PID(s).